# File size obtained via du smaller than ls

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage

I used both `du -h` and `ls -lah` to find the size of a core file:

```
$ du -h core.app.1665679445 
2.0M    core.app.1665679445

$ ls -lah core.app.1665679445 
-rw------- 1 262899 10000 31M Oct 13 16:44 core.app.1665679445
```

Unless I'm wrong, `ls` returns the actual file size and `du` the total space of the I/O blocks occupied by the file (i.e., number of blocks multiplied by the I/O block size). Therefore, `du` should always return a larger size than `ls` (see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371238/what-is-the-difference-between-file-size-in-ls-l-and-du-sh). However, my case is the opposite. How is possible?

Comment: Sparse file? What filesystem do you use?

Comment: It's XFS. But well, sparse file can really be the case.